# How to achieve arbitrary chain on function call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, chaining

I have written code to achieve

```
sum(1)(2) //3
```

the code looks like:

```
function sum(a) {

  return function(b) { 
    return a+b
 }

}
```

But I didn't work out the second question, which is how to achieve any arbitrary number of chain function call like:

```
sum(1)(2) == 3
sum(5)(-1)(2) == 6
sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) == 0
sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) == 15
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally you'd do something like this:

```
var add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

var sum = function(){
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, add);
}
```

And then you can write:

```
sum(1,2,3,4); // 10
```

But it is possible to hack the functionality you're after:

```
var sum = function(x){
    var f = function(y){
        return sum(x+y);
    };
    f.valueOf = function(){
        return x;
    };
    return f;
};

sum(1)(2)(3)(4); // 10
```

Just don't do it in production code please!

Comment: This is very clever. Probably too clever for real-world use, as your answer suggests. Nevertheless, it's accurate and very thought-provoking.

Comment: Very nice!
You can also add
`f.toString = function(){
            return x+"";
 };`
to allow for stuff like `alert(sum(1)(2)(3)(4))` if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this - how does the `sum` function know whether you want it to return the answer or another function?

You could do something along these lines though:

```
sum(0)(1)(2)(3).result()
```

Implemented like this:

```
var sum = (function(){
    var total = 0;
    var f = function(n){
        total += n;
        return f;
    };
    f.result = function(){
        return total;
    };
    return f;
}());
```

Comment: thx, but that is a question on book, so I think it is able to do that somehow.

Comment: I would be very interested to see the answer if you find it, seems like it would need to return a number that was also a function

Comment: @codebox see mintsauce's answer that overrides the returned function's valueOf method.

Answer (score 1):

As user codebox already said: This is not possible.

What you can do instead is to take the current parameter of the function into account. If there is no parameter you can return the result:

```
sum(1)(2)() == 3
```

Here is the implementation:

```
var sum = (function() {
    var total = 0;
    return function add(a) {
        if(a === undefined) {
            return total;
        }
        total += a;
        return add;
    };
}());
```

Comment: nice, closer to what he is asking for than mine

Answer (score 0):

There's a handful of different ways to pass an "arbitrary" amount of arguments to a function. Perhaps the most useful for your case is the `arguments` object. In the scope of every function is an array-like object that holds all of the arguments passed to the function.

```
function shout(msg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        console.log(arguments[i]);
}

shout("This", "is", "JavaScript!"); // Logs all three strings, one line at a time
```

Despite it seeming like the function only accepts one argument, you can plug in as many as you'd like, and the function will cycle through all of them. Thus, converting this for your code:

```
function sum(a) {
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        total = total + arguments[i];

    return total;
}

sum(1, 2); // Returns 3
```

Two things to note:

- Because you're accessing the arguments object, you really don't "need" any sort of arguments list in the function definition (i.e. you don't need the `a` in `sum(a)`), but it's generally considered a good idea to provide some indication of what the function expects.
- The arguments object is array-*like*, but is NOT a true array; don't go trying to use array functions on it such as push or pop unless you want to make a mess of things.

As for the specific `sum(1)(2)` syntax however--if that is very specifically what you need--I'm stumped. In theory, to have an arbitrary chain like that, you'd need your function to return an object that is *both* a function and a number... which breaks fundamental rules of JavaScript. I don't think it's possible without some extremely clever (and likely extremely dangerous) editing of built in objects, which is generally frowned upon unless there is an extremely good reason for doing so.