# Reimplementing UnderscoreJS chaining in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

First off,
I read the [related articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736241/is-this-the-right-way-to-implement-chaining-in-javascript) on this and felt they were unsuitable to me since I am using a series of methods I am inheriting and not a few arithmetic functions I can easily change. Secondly, googling `'javascript chaining method'` has results mostly concerning jQuery and D3. The JavaScript `chain` method is surprisingly under-documented it seems.

I am trying to [implement underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) in CoffeeScript. I am working on the `_.chain` method. I am decorating underscore methods to `newObject` and then returning it. I have a private variable called `value` which is suppose to be the value that is modified by chained method calls. Calling `getValue()` on the returned `newObject` should return the private `value` variable.

For some reason though the private `value` variable is not changing when I call a method on `newObject`. The underscore methods are being curried correctly, but they do not change when a function is invoked. I tried reading the [underscore source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) but it seems they architect there chain method in a completely different way that I cannot duplicate without restructuring the way my underscore object is constructed.

**_.chain**

```
_.chain = (v) ->
  newObj = {}
  value = v
  newObj.getValue = -> value
  for name, fn of _
    if typeof fn is 'function'
      newObj[name] = (callback, otherVal) ->
        value = fn(value, callback, otherVal)
        newObj
  newObj
```

**Example:**

```
var a = _.chain([1,2,3,4]);
a.map(function(value) {
  return value + 5;
})
a.getValue().getValue()
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @Mathletics Implementing something yourself is a great way to understand how said thing works.

A better question to ask: why do you need to call `getValue` twice? I'd bet that the reason you need to do that is the same reason the function isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the behaviour of closures (this is javascript after all). The problem shows up here:

```
newObj[name] = (callback, otherVal) ->
  value = fn(value, callback, otherVal)
  newObj
```

The value of `fn` is closed over, to be used whenever the function associated with `name` is called on `newObj`. The problem is that the value of `fn` changes throughout the lifecycle of the `chain` function, and so the closed-over value will change as well. In particular, after `chain` exits, the value of `fn` in the closures for each underscore function you've attached to `newObj` will be whatever function is iterated last in the `for name, fn of _` loop. In this case, that function is `chain`, so when you are calling `map` in your example, when the interpreter hits the line `value = fn(value, callback, otherVal)`, `fn` is the `chain` function.

This is why you need to call `getValue` twice in your example: `a.map(...)` is calling `chain` internally, so it returns a chained, chained object.

In order to fix this, we can use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that instead of closing over `fn`, the functions you attach to `newObj` close over the actual function you want:

```
newObj[name] = ((f) ->
  (callback, otherVal) ->
    value = f(value, callback, otherVal)
    newObj
  )(fn)
```

Now, instead of closing over `fn` to be used later (and later, it won't be the `fn` we want), we close over `f`, which we immediately bind to be the *current* value of `fn`.

Here is the full fixed version, in Coffeescript:

```
_.chain = (v) ->
  newObj = {}
  value = v
  newObj.getValue = -> value
  for name, fn of _
    if typeof fn is 'function'
      newObj[name] = ((f) ->
        (callback, otherVal) ->
          value = f(value, callback, otherVal)
          newObj
      )(fn)
  newObj
```

You can check it with your example and see that it gives the correct answer now.